# How do write a SOQL join between contact and custom object?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I need to get contacts with related table "Candidate_Farm_Assignment_c",
the thing is i want that it will pull only the records that have a specific value from "Candidates_Farms_Assignments"

```
SELECT Name, Birth_Country__c,
(SELECT Candidate__c,**Farm__c** FROM Candidates_Farms_Assignments__r) 
FROM Contact
WHERE **Farm__c**  = '00558000001NEZoAAO'
```

**How can i do that?**

Comment: You can do something like this:
`SELECT Name, Birth_Country__c FROM Contact WHERE ID IN (SELECT **Contact Lookup Field Here** FROM Candidates_Farms_Assignment__c Where Farm__c = '00558000001NEZoAAO')`

Comment: OR if you need fields from the child object too then try this:
`SELECT Candidate__c, Farm__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Birth_Country__c 
FROM Candidates_Farms_Assignment__c Where Farm__c  = '00558000001NEZoAAO'` I supposed that `Contact__r` is the Contact's lookup field API name.

Comment: thanx @abdn, but i dont need the 'Id', the comparison is in  "Farm__c" field.

Comment: actually, @abdn gave you a correct solution(even two, but the second one's preferable IMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do so is to query Candidates_Farms_Assignments__c records with needed parent fields and set condition in this query:

```
SELECT Candidate__c, Farm__c, Contact.Name, Contact.Birth_Country__c 
FROM Candidates_Farms_Assignments__c WHERE Farm__c = '00558000001NEZoAAO'
```

By querying this you will get only records where Farm__c equals to the given Id and you could access needed contact fields via dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `WHERE` clause to your `Left Outer Join`:

```
SELECT Name, Birth_Country__c,
    (
        SELECT Candidate__c, Farm__c FROM Candidates_Farms_Assignments__r WHERE Farm__c = '<some_id>'
    )
FROM Contact
```

It's worth noting you should never use hard-coded Ids under any circumstances.